# Magento product Images are uploading but not showing up after upload in backend and frontend

Tags: magento-1.9, product-images, image-upload, product-edit

[image]When trying to upload a product image, it stays stuck on "Complete", like this and nothing happens.

My Magento version is 1.9.3.2 I've changed the media folder permissions also checked removing the cache storage, flushed the Magento cache, reindexed the data, and nothing seems to be working.

Have also enabled all php extensions.